# Delete matrix row where rownames() are NA with R

Tags: r

I have matrix that looks like this:

```
     [,1]
A    "2012" 
B    "2013"
C    "2012"
D    "2013"
NA1  "2012" 
NA2  "2013"
NA3  "2013"
NA4  "2014"
```

How can I delete the last rows given the names `NA1, NA2`....?

So that the final result is like this:

```
        [,1]
  A    "2012" 
  B    "2013"
  C    "2012"
  D    "2013"
```

EDIT: I have tried going this way...

```
ifelse(nchar(rownames(Matrx))<2,Matrx,!(nchar(rownames(Matrx))>2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and `grepl` to remove them.

```
> M <- matrix(c("2012","2013","2012","2013","2012","2013","2013","2014"))
> rownames(M) <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'NA1', 'NA2', 'NA3', 'NA4')
> M
##     [,1]  
## A   "2012"
## B   "2013"
## C   "2012"
## D   "2013"
## NA1 "2012"
## NA2 "2013"
## NA3 "2013"
## NA4 "2014"

> as.matrix(M[!grepl('NA', rownames(M)), ])
##   [,1]  
## A "2012"
## B "2013"
## C "2012"
## D "2013"
```